# Android SQLite: Database empty in second activity

Tags: android, sqlite

I've searched all over the net for a solution to this so lets hope someone here can help.

My app has a start up task which populates a SQLite database before loading the main menu. A second activity that can be accessed from the main menu needs access to this. Therefore I close the database in the first activity in order to stop locking errors.

For some reason, the database seems to have no rows as soon as I close the connection, in both the same activity and the second activity.

Heres a code sample:

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase(); // get instance of current database 

    db.beginTransaction(); // set exclusive mode to speed up

    for(GulbArticle g : gulbArticles){
        this.insert(g);
    }

    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    // counting here returns 315 rows using the all2() function below
    db.close();
    // counting here returns 0 rows using the all2() function below
```

Here is a function I made to get the count back

```
public void all2(){
      SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
      String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "+TABLE_NAME;
      SQLiteStatement statement =db.compileStatement(sql);
        long count = statement.simpleQueryForLong();
        Log.v("ccount2",count+"");
}
```

So in both cases I'm initializing an instance of the database, but for some reason as soon as I close it once I can't reopen it/there seems to be nothing in the database. Maybe I'm missing something simple but this has really stumped me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you forgot to call `db.endTransaction();`, i.e. to commit the transaction.
It should read:

```
db.setTransactionSuccessful();
db.endTransaction();
db.close();
```

Also it is good idea to surround it in try-catch-finaly like this:

```
try {
    db.beginTransaction();
    // do your DB manipulation
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
} catch(...) { 
    ...
} finally {
    db.endTransaction();
}

db.close();
```

Comment: Sorted, I for some reason assumed `db.setTransactionSuccessful()` would close it but I guess that just toggles a boolean. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to close database when you start second activity. SQLite is normal DB management system - which means that these kind of situation should be resolved.

Resolving of this usually done by transactions mechanism - which you're tried to use in your code.

In your case I believe you have to use non-eclusive transactions - i.e. when record is locked in exclusive mode - record in unaccessible, so basic idiom should looks like:

```
db.beginTransactionNonExclusive();   
try 
{     
   // do smth     
   db.setTransactionSuccessful();   
} 
finally 
{     
   db.endTransaction();   
}
```

Comment: I don't seem to have access to that NonExclusive function but thanks for pointing that out I'll investigate a bit further

Comment: Unfortunatly, the beginTransactionNonExclusive() is only avaialable in API level 11 (android 3.0) or newer...